# How can I make R send an alert if it encounters an error?

Tags: r, error-handling, notifications

I currently enjoy receiving email notifications when my R scripts have finished running, thanks to the `mail` package.

However, I would like to know if it's possible to have R (or RStudio, or something else) notify me if a script fails to finish running because it has encountered an error? Email would be the best delivery method.

This would be extremely useful when I'm running code on a remote machine, or when I'm away from my computer.

Comment: Use `try` or `tryCatch` to handle the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can make tryCatch work. Is there anything more general than that, though? Something that could be triggered by *any* error, regardless of where it occurred in the script?

Comment: tryCatch is extremely general. You just need a separate script that calls your script: `tryCatch(expr = {source(my_script)}, ...)`. I suppose you could wrap your entire script in `tryCatch`, but a separate script seems cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a pushbullet message: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPushbullet/index.html

Or send yourself an email: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mailR/

And use tryCatch...

```
a <- tryCatch({
    source("your_script.R")
}, warning = function(w) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(e) {
    send mail, pushbullet, etc...
}, finally = {
    cleanup
}
```

Comment: Since OP says he mails himself when scripts finish, my guess is the trouble is error handling not sending the message.

Comment: Yes, I mean if R encounters an error for any reason.