# Is there a way to beep / play a sound in the motherboard at the end of a script?

Tags: r, motherboard

In my work, I cannot use a speaker. When I run R scripts I go do something else on a different desktop. If I don't check frequently, I never know when something is finished. Is there a way to invoke a beep in the motherboard via some code at the end of my script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3365657/7128934

Comment: @d.b  I know that, but these solutions will need an external speaker.

Comment: Here are some non-audio alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886696/how-can-i-make-r-send-an-alert-if-it-encounters-an-error